# Why echo does not print the first part of the text

Tags: php, echo

Why this only print out "-1". What happens to the first part of the text.

```
echo "2 results of this " .    "Apples" <=> "bananas";
```

Thanks

Comment: Use parentheses surrounding ```("Apples" <=>"bananas")```

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar.

Comment: And Sumit and everyone who has kindly answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than `<=>`, so it's parsed as if you'd written:

```
echo ("2 results of this " . "Apples") <=> "bananas";
```

which is equivalent to:

```
echo "2 results of this Apples" <=> "bananas";
```

So it's comparing these two strings and printing just the result.

Add parentheses to get what you want:

```
echo "2 results of this " . ("Apples" <=> "bananas");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it will 1st concatenate the string and then will apply the spaceship operator comparison

"

```
2 results of this " .    "Apples" <=> "bananas"; = -1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^
string1                               string2
```

try below

```
  $spaceship_result=  "Apples" <=> "bananas";
  echo "2 results of this ".$spaceship_result;
```

Comment: If your answer doesn't solve OP's problem then he has to explain his issue better. I'm just wondering where "2 results of this -1" is being used lol. But yeah OP, sumit's answer solves your issue.